# Not printing "id" when called in HTML from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I am working on an assignment where I have to pull quote and a name from a randomized array of such and display them in my HTML page. under some filler text. For what ever reason the script is running and displaying a different id (a simple local date a time display) but not the quote randomizer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>CIS  - 16W</h1>
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../p1/assign1/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="../p1/assign2/">Assignment 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="../p1/assign3/">Assignment 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="../p1/assign4/">Assignment 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="../p1/assign5/">Assignment 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="../p1/assign6/">Assignment 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="../p1/assign7/">Assignment 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="../p1/fp/">Final Project</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name=“description” content=“description”>
        <meta name=“author” content=“your”>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
        <script src="../functions.js"></script>
<main>
    <p>My name is _____ and I am a junior here at the _____.<br>I'm very excited to get started and hone in my skills in the multimedia environment!
    </p>
    <p>I am taking this course to help not only fill the math requirment for a Bacholer of Science, but also to aid my Multimedia minor and Advertising major!</p>
    <span id="quote"></span>
    <span id="name"></span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function () {
setInterval(timeAndDate, 1000);
}


var quotes = ["\"How many cares one loses when one decides not to be something but to be someone.\"",
"\"If you want to test a man's character give him power.\"",
"\"I just hope that one day, perferably when we're both blind drunk, we can talk about it\"",
"\"Why do you look so sad?'<br>'Because you speak to me in words and I look at you with feelings.\"",
"\"Courage is what it takes to stand up and speak. Courage is also what it takes to sit down and listen.\""];
var names = ["-Coco Chanel", "-Abrham Lincoln", "-J. D. Salinger", "-Leo Tolstoy", "-Wiston Churchill"];

var arrIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));

function quoteGen() {
    var quoteAll = document.getElementById("quote");
    var namesAll = document.getElementById("name");
    quoteAll.innerHTML = quotes[arrIndex];
    namesAll.innerHTML = names[arrIndex];
    if (arrIndex > quotes.length-1) {
        arrIndex = 0;
    }
}


function timeAndDate() {
    var date = new Date();
    var n = date.toDateString();
    var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById('localDate').innerHTML = n + ' ' + time;
}
```

Comment: there is no `localDate` in the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems here,

- You are not calling `quoteGen` which is updating the quotes, the timer need to call `quoteGen` but you are calling `timeAndDate` that is why the timing is getting updated, not the quotes
- You need to generate the random index within `quoteGen` so that every invocation will get a new random value

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(quoteGen, 1000);
}


var quotes = ["\"How many cares one loses when one decides not to be something but to be someone.\"",
  "\"If you want to test a man's character give him power.\"",
  "\"I just hope that one day, perferably when we're both blind drunk, we can talk about it\"",
  "\"Why do you look so sad?'<br>'Because you speak to me in words and I look at you with feelings.\"",
  "\"Courage is what it takes to stand up and speak. Courage is also what it takes to sit down and listen.\""
];
var names = ["-Coco Chanel", "-Abrham Lincoln", "-J. D. Salinger", "-Leo Tolstoy", "-Wiston Churchill"];

var idx;

function quoteGen() {
  //the looping is used to make sure that every call to quoteGen will update a new quote
  do {
    var arrIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
  } while (idx == arrIndex);
  idx = arrIndex;
  var quoteAll = document.getElementById("quote");
  var namesAll = document.getElementById("name");
  quoteAll.innerHTML = quotes[arrIndex];
  namesAll.innerHTML = names[arrIndex];
}
```

```html
<p>My name is _____ and I am a junior here at the _____.
  <br>I'm very excited to get started and hone in my skills in the multimedia environment!
</p>
<p>I am taking this course to help not only fill the math requirment for a Bacholer of Science, but also to aid my Multimedia minor and Advertising major!</p>
<span id="quote"></span>
<span id="name"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling quoteGen() anywhere.